# Load previous month or given start and end date in full calender initially

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalender in my page. I have imported necessary packages. when i load page it's displaying current month calender in fullcalender view. But i want to display previous month or given start and end date in full calender view initially. Can anyone help me to do that.

```
(function() {
    var cal, calendarDate, d, m, y;

    this.setDraggableEvents = function() {
      return $("#events .external-event").each(function() {
        var eventObject;
        eventObject = {
          title: $.trim($(this).text())
        };
        $(this).data("eventObject", eventObject);
        return $(this).draggable({
          zIndex: 999,
          revert: true,
          revertDuration: 0
        });
      });
    };

    calendarDate = new Date();

    d = calendarDate.getDate();

    m = calendarDate.getMonth();

    y = calendarDate.getFullYear();

    cal = $(".full-calendar-demo").fullCalendar({
      header: {
        center: "title",
        left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek",
        right: "prev,today,next"
      },
      buttonIcons: {
        prev: "fa-chevron-left",
        next: "fa-chevron-right"
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: "Today",
        agendaDay: "Day",
        agendaWeek: "Week",
        month: "Month",
        listWeek: "List"
      },
      droppable: true,
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        return bootbox.prompt("Event title", function(title) {
          if (title !== null) {
            cal.fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
              title: title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              allDay: allDay
            }, true);
            return cal.fullCalendar('unselect');
          }
        });
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        return bootbox.dialog({
          message: $("<form class='form'><label>Change event name</label></form><input id='new-event-title' class='form-control' type='text' value='" + calEvent.title + "' /> "),
          buttons: {
            "delete": {
              label: "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete Event",
              className: "pull-left",
              callback: function() {
                return cal.fullCalendar("removeEvents", function(ev) {
                  return ev._id === calEvent._id;
                });
              }
            },
            success: {
              label: "<i class='fa fa-floppy-o'></i> Save",
              className: "btn-success",
              callback: function() {
                calEvent.title = $("#new-event-title").val();
                return cal.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      },
      drop: function(date, allDay) {
        var copiedEventObject, eventClass, originalEventObject;
        originalEventObject = $(this).data("eventObject");
        originalEventObject.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
        eventClass = $(this).attr('data-event-class');
        console.log(originalEventObject);
        copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        if (eventClass) {
          copiedEventObject["className"] = [eventClass];
        }
        $(".full-calendar-demo").fullCalendar("renderEvent", copiedEventObject, true);
        if ($("#calendar-remove-after-drop").is(":checked")) {
          return $(this).remove();
        }
      },
      events: [
        {
          id: "event1",
          title: "All Day Event",
          start: moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          className: 'event-orange'
        }, {
          id: "event2",
          title: "Long Event",
          start: moment().subtract(5, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          end: moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          className: "event-red"
        },
      ]
    });

  });
```

Please look at the above code and help me to do that.

Comment: include your code

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defaultDate`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) to specify the starting date.

```
// Use moment to get the date 1 month ago (Fullcalendar uses moment, you already 
// have it available)
var startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'month');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: startDate
});
```